# Can I use an old Mobile Phone as a FCT

Tags: communication, cellphone

I have a PSTN Home Alarm System and an old GSM cell phones lying around in the house.  Is it possible to use this old GSM cell phone as a FCT for my  alarm system?

Comment: what is a FCT in this context?

Comment: -1 for not explaining what FCT means. (Some users may not even know what a PSTN is.)

Comment: FCT = Fixed Cellular Terminal. [Example](http://www.prudhvitelecom.com/fixed-cellular-terminals.html), and [another](http://www.witura.com/products/telecommunication-industry/gsm-fixed-wireless-terminal.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, but really only as a slightly hackish solution. Many old phones - particularly Nokia (which is the biggest majority of legacy non-smartphones) - have a very easy to interface serial port on their connector pinout. Most alarm systems can be configured to use this serial port to dial, as this is the same method as using an external modem. If you don't have such a port, you can hack something together with an arduino really easily. So from the technical side it's probably really easy to do this.

The problem lies within the type of connection you are establishing. Depending on what carrier you plan on using and what coverage you like to have, you might have pretty poor connection rates, the carrier may terminate the connection quickly after it starts or data may not transfer at all. Mobile phones often exclusively use voice codecs even when dialing from the serial port, which distorts the tones you are sending to your alarm service provider. This is of course no problem if you are using SMS or MMS to send alarm data.

Another problem with the voice type of connection is that carriers often detect whether there is voice or other data, and will aggressively terminate the connection if you are trying to do something other than talk to people with the connection. This is because they often have separate plans for this kind of use of their mobile systems (a plan which is used for things like smart meters, traffic signs, public transport information signs and weather/telemetry applications). You can experiment with this, it varies with the evilness of your local ISPs.

The last problem is that availability of GSM/WCDMA is not great. You're usually looking at sub-98% uptimes, often with very large gaps of coverage every so often (hours of no service). This is no problem for applications in the open field because other towers will take over the traffic, but older phones with worse reception may not get a good signal. This is why many alarm systems still use the pager network - something that has been shut off very recently where I live, but is still active in many other countries. Pager networks have failsafes on the network equipment in every tower, so you have much better coverage even when you're dependent on a single cell tower. Unfortunately, a pager contract is really expensive compared to basically all other plans.